# Convert List to Dictionary<string, string[]>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple custom object:

```
class CertQuestion
{
    public string Field {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Subsequently I find myself with a List in some code. I'm trying to figure out how to format a list of CertQuestions into a corresponding Dictionary with similar Field names grouped together. For instance, given the following list:

```
        List<CertQuestion> certQuestions = new List<CertQuestion>()
            {
                new CertQuestion("Key", "Value1"),
                new CertQuestion("Key", "Value2"),
                new CertQuestion("Key2", "Value"),
                new CertQuestion("Key2", "Value2")
            };
```

I would like to convert that (trying to use LINQ) into a Dictionary with two entries such as

```
{{"Key", "Value1, Value2"}, {"Key2", "Value, Value2"}}
```

Comment: So you want a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`?

Comment: So what problem(s) are you having creating this dictionary?

Comment: `certQuestions.ToLookup(x => x.Field, x => x.Value);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Group the questions by field, then convert to dictionary by selecting key, then value. Value becomes the grouping's list.

```
certQuestions.GroupBy(c => c.Field)
             .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(f => f.Value).ToList())
```

Or for an array:

```
certQuestions.GroupBy(c => c.Field)
             .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(f => f.Value).ToArray())
```

Edit based on question in comment:

```
class CertTest 
{
    public string TestId {get;set;}
    public List<CertQuestion> Questions {get;set;}
}
var certTests = new List<CertTest>();
```

You would use the SelectMany extension method. It is designed to aggregate a property list object that is in each element of the original list:

```
certTests.SelectMany(t => t.Questions)
         .GroupBy(c => c.Field)
         .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(f => f.Value).ToList())
```

Comment: Not quite right, that'll give you a `Dictionary<string,List<CertQuestion>>`. You need to `Select` the `Value`. Something like `.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(cq => cq.Value).ToList())`

Comment: Yes you are right, missed the string type vs. CertQuestion type in desired result.

Comment: It always seems so simple after someone has explained how to do it. Just out of curiosity, what if I had a list of objects and each object had a List<CertQuestion>, how could I wrap up all the objects' List<CertQuesion> fields into a single Dictionary<string, string[]>?

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement was for a comma-separated list of values, that can be done like this:

```
var dict = certQuestions.GroupBy(c => c.Field)
             .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => String.Join(", ", v.Select(x => x.Value)))
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/LXS58744

(You should consider whether what you *actually* want is the values to be an `Array` or `List<string>` - see other answers)